# How do I uninstall Xubuntu on Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, xubuntu

I just installed Xubuntu on my computer because I thought it would run faster on my computer. I didn't click try Xubuntu because I didn't want to wait 2 hours. It took 40 minutes just to boot up that try Xubuntu or install Xubuntu screen. I am new to Linux and I don't know anything about it except that it's underrated and it runs fast. I enabled an option that lets me have allocated stuff. I have 160GB of storage for Xubuntu and 160GB of storage for Ubuntu. I want to know how to uninstall Xubuntu and leave Ubuntu on here without deleting any of my files on Ubuntu, and I also want to unallocate the random stuff I don't know about.

Comment: You do not uninstall an OS. Run gparted and delete the partition it was in. BUT before you do that when you boot the computer do you get a Grub menu offering to select which OS?

Comment: yes, I do have a GRUB menu.

Comment: It does have the entries for the 2 OS.

Comment: OK well after using gparted to remove the partition for the OS you do not want you will need to do a boot repair to update the grub to remove the entry for the removed OS. https://www.javatpoint.com/boot-repair-ubuntu

Comment: gparted isn't letting me remove the partition.

Comment: That is an active partition then. Make sure you are trying to remove the correct one.

Comment: Well, I guess all the partitions are active then.

Comment: Not possible. Anyway this is not something I think you are going to be able to do. I suggest boot from the Live Media of the OS you want to use and do a fresh default install using the whole drive. https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview

Comment: There's no need to dual boot.  Xubuntu Desktop works just fine with Ubuntu.  `sudo apt install xubuntu-desktop`  Then choose it at the login prompt.